# WSO2 identiy server - How to map a User Store to a service provider for Authentication?

Tags: active-directory, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to build an application which is going to use WSO2 identity server to authenticate with IDP initiated SSO .

I have tried out the travelocity.com example in the WSO2IS tutorials , and I can understand that the "default" authentication type as Local Outbound Authentication uses the Primary user store to perform authentication :

[image]

What I need to understand is , how do I map a UserStore to work with a particular service provider , I am performing SSO as IDP initiated ?

Is it something I can manage inside the WSO2 Management Console ?  **OR** do I have to modify the **authenticationendpoint** webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't limited to the PRIMARY user store and if you have multiple secondary user stores, it'll try to authenticate the user with every user store until the authentication is success.

Limiting a user store to a certain service provider is currently not available in the Identity Server but you can write a custom authenticator and achieve this requirement. Here is a [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+Local+Authenticator) on how to write a custom local authenticator. Basically what you have to do is, overide the `processAuthenticationResponse` method and pick the user store accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jayanga, Could you please share exact line of codes to get specific user store in method  "processAuthenticationResponse" ?? Assuming I have a secondry user store "CustomUserStore".

Comment: You can use following code to get the PRIMARY user store and from it you can get the secondaries as well. UserStoreManager userStoreManager = (UserStoreManager) BasicCustomAuthenticatorServiceComponent.getRealmService().getTenantUserRealm(tenantId).getUserStoreManager();

Answer (score 0):

Based on you described requirement, I would like to suggest another approach to achieve the same.

In WSO2 Identity Server you have the capability engage a policy in the authentication flow. So using a policy we can restrict which user stores are allowed for a particular service provider.

Check out https://medium.com/@Pushpalanka/application-wise-authorization-wso2-identity-server-user-store-per-service-provider-dfea5f9ad758 for a detailed explaination.